# What is wrong with my FFMPEG command for streaming?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to stream to Facebook by using one image, but I get

`Packets are not in the proper order with respect to DTS7kbits/s

av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument`

This is the command I am writing:

```
ffmpeg \
-re -y \
-loop 1 \
-f image2 \
-i ./maxresdefault.jpg \
-i ./audio.mp3 \
-b:a 128k \
-c:a aac -strict experimental \
-vcodec libx264 \
-g 30 \
-r 30 \
-f flv \
"rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/..."
```

Comment: What's different about this question than the [similar question you asked an hour earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310387/ffmpeg-conversion-failed-error-when-trying-trying-to-create-facebook-stream-fr)?

Comment: different configuration